# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Tridion's [second moderator election](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive "graduation" election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:

[image: Anand N S]

[image: Velmurugan]

[image: Marko Milic]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: Congratulations Anand, Velu, and Marko. Great to have you as our moderators!

Comment: Congrats guys, I am really happy to have you around and leading this awesome community